# Laguerre's method

Tags: numerical-methods, polynomials, polynomial-math, newtons-method

I'm trying to implement Laguerre's method for following equation:

`1/(99*x+1)=2`. (general form is more complex - polynomial of n-th degree `1/(a*x+1)+...+1/(z*x+1)=res`) where `a,b,...z>=0` and `0<res<N`

but it quickly terminates and goes to infinity.

Solution for this case is very simple - `-0.00505050505050505`.

Since they say that Laguerre's method is working in 99.999% of cases, I hope this is not that 0.001?

Is there some other way that I could use to polynomial roots that is working in all cases? I need just one real root (and there is always 1 in my case).

Comment: Could you give a little more details on how you implemented Laguerre's method for a non-polynomial expression? And then perhaps a test example where the method failed? In the first example, for `n=1` the method reduces to Newton, which should converge quadratically for `abs(2(99*x+1)-1)<1`, but outside the interval `(-1/99,0)` you indeed get divergence to infinity with a quadratic order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laguerres method works for polynomials exclusively, so you need to first transform your expressions into a polynomial form. Your first equation then becomes linear, which any method solves in one step. Your general problem has the form `1/x*q'(1/x)/q(1/x)=res` with `q(z)=(z+a1)*...*(z+an)`, so that the polynomial is `z*q'(z)-res*q(z)` or `x^(n-1)*q'(1/x)-res*x^n*q(1/x)`.

If you want a third order method for general functions, try the Halley method.

Comment: Isnt linear - polynomial of 1st degree? I thought it should work for all polynomials?

Comment: Your expression is not linear, it is hyperbolic. The general expression is a rational function, a quotient of polynomials. You can transform it into a polynomial equation, but in general the numerical methods for equivalent equations give different iteration sequences. You can easily check the Newton method for `x^2-a`, `x-a/x` and `1-a/x^2`, the resulting fixed-point iterations are all different.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to convert that form to polynomial form and try again with newton method (or Laguerre;s)? Not sure if I wrote general case correctly, so I will do it again (since I'm not sure if your form of general problem is same as mine) : e.g. for level 3 polynomial I have `(1/(a*x+1)) + (1/(b*x+1)) + (1/(c*x+1)) = d` where a,b,c,d are constants. Is your definition of general problem still the same?

Comment: You can use Newton's method or even the original or usual version of Halley's method directly for this rational expression. As Laguerre is still an order 3 method for any value of `n`, you can even use this, for general expressions of 3 or more terms it has a good chance to also converge globally. Note that you get also problems with Laguerre with the unit-root polynomials `x^n-1`, but afaik only with those.